# Analogue of dladdr on Integrity OS?

Tags: c++, c, callstack, integrity, greenhills

Is there a way to get all non-POSIX things from *dlfcn.h* working on Integrity OS when using ghs compiler? Here is a list: *dladdr* function, *Dl_info* structure.

Comment: Are these non-posix things actually implemented on that OS?

Comment: hope so, that's why asking. what can be found in manuals is only function void *__builtin_return_address(unsigned int level); which doesn't provide all needed info.